# Expand $PATH problem $HOME/bin is set twice

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using in xubuntu bionic as shell bash.

I'll try to expand my $PATH for my user over $HOME/.profile.

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

The result is a little bit unexpected.

```
echo $PATH
/home/alex/.local/bin:/home/alex/bin:/home/alex/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

$HOME/bin is set twice. How can I avoid it?

In $HOME/.bashrc is nothing declared.

Comment: The lines you show should exist by default in `$HOME/.profile` since the are copied from `/etc/skel/.profile` when you created the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Stephen Collyer's "Bash Path Functions" (see his article [Stephen Collyer's article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645) in Linux Journal). It permits me to use the "colon separated list" as a datatype in shell programming. For example, I can produce a list of all the directories in the current directory by:

```
dirs="";for i in * ; do if [ -d $i ] ; then addpath -p dirs $i; fi; done
```

Then, listpath -p dirs produces a list.

Using `uniqpath` and `listpath` (from bash_path_funcs), one could simply:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
+walt@bat:~(0)$ listpath
/home/walt/bin
/home/walt/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/home/walt/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin

+walt@bat:~(0)$ uniqpath -p PATH
+walt@bat:~(0)$ listpath
/home/walt/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/gameswalt@bat:~(0)$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: this looks interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is already configured to automatically add `$HOME/bin` to the path.

You mentioned you're distribution was Server converted to Desktop and I'm not sure how that effects things but you can check:

```bash
$ cat ~/.profile

# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

It sounds like this is being executed and what you are manually doing is doubling up on the last line in the file.

---

### Using `grep` to find all references

You can use grep to find all the files where `$HOME/bin` is referenced:

```bash
grep -rnw --exclude-dir={proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e "$HOME/bin"
```

Comment: No, it was not.

Comment: I'm at work but when I get home I'll find the exact place it is set and update the answer. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: unmodified user  `echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` as I wrote xubuntu bionic. with cfce4-session. It was a server installation first ;D

Comment: The current .profile checks for the existence of a bin or .local/bin before adding it to the PATH.  @nobody an unmodified user will not have a bin directory, so in that case, not adding the bin to the PATH is correct.

Comment: @ubfan1 When I checked `/etc/skel/.profile` it is identical. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS though.

Comment: Bingo, testie has no $HOME/bin. so no expantion. I become old.